# Ionic/Angular application with MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, ionic-framework, database

I'm currently building an application using the Ionic framework and also implementing AngularJS on top of that.

I have the core application built in terms of the view files, I am using templates in my www folder and I also have controllers for each page that I have built and I'm using URL states to navigate from page to page in my app.js file.

This is where my issue arises, where do I create the models? at the moment I have a seperate models file with my MongoDB schema in there, do i create controllers for these db's and that's where I add my functionality?

However I am encountering several issues. I'm quite new to mobile development and I know the documentation for Ionic states that is no correct way of implementing a db into your build.

So I have been trying to use MongoDB. However I have no idea if i'm doing it correctly at all. This is my first ever question on Stack Overflow so I do apologize for the lack of information.

If you need to know specifics please tell me what to provide and I can do that no problem. I was really just looking for some guidance as I'm at a loss for what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.